# erratic_navigation error before costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, erratic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with the navigation stack. I use Fuerte and tried to run a simulation with the erratic robot:

roslaunch erratic_navigation move_base_local.launch

….

```
NODES
  /move_base_node/local_costmap/
    voxel_grid_throttle (topic_tools/throttle)
  /
    move_base_node (move_base/move_base)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [25088]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 27570100-fe93-11e2-bc47-002622350f36
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [25101]
started core service [/rosout]
process[move_base_node/local_costmap/voxel_grid_throttle-2]: started with pid [25113]
process[move_base_node-3]: started with pid [25127]
[ INFO] [1375791876.551792597]: Subscribed to Topics: base_scan base_scan_marking
[ WARN] [1375791881.653678739]: Waiting on transform from /base_footprint to /odom to become available before running costmap, tf error:
```

and with: roslaunch erratic_navigation_apps erratic_2dnav.launch
...

```
NODES
  /move_base_node/local_costmap/
    voxel_grid_throttle (topic_tools/throttle)
  /
    amcl (amcl/amcl)
    move_base_node (move_base/move_base)
    voxel_visualizer (costmap_2d/costmap_2d_markers)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [25999]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 6caa4438-fe93-11e2-9666-002622350f36
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [26012]
started core service [/rosout]
process[amcl-2]: started with pid [26024]
process[move_base_node/local_costmap/voxel_grid_throttle-3]: started with pid [26081]
[ INFO] [1375791992.682028086]: Requesting the map...
[ WARN] [1375791992.683369458]: Request for map failed; trying again...
process[move_base_node-4]: started with pid [26130]
process[voxel_visualizer-5]: started with pid [26145]
[ INFO] [1375791993.099960562]: Subscribed to Topics: base_scan base_scan_marking
[ INFO] [1375791993.122128742]: Requesting the map...

[ INFO] [1375791993.124315334]: Still waiting on map...

[ WARN] [1375791993.184716658]: Request for map failed; trying again...
```

I guess they are connected, but I don't know where the problem is. Just installed it and tried to launch it and make the first steps. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71413/erratic_navigation-error-before-costmap/) by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) on 2013-08-06**:
This works, for whatever the reason: roslaunch erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_slam.launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to start first the Gazebo simulator and set up a robot model like this:

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
roslaunch erratic_description erratic_mobile_base.launch
```

And then:

```
roslaunch erratic_description erratic_mobile_base.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [DIDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/4231/didi/) with karma: 32 on 2013-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0